# Restricting AWS Step Functions to have only one execution running at a time

Tags: locking, aws-step-functions

I want to limit the number of executions of my step functions to 1 at any given time. Is there a way to put a global lock on AWS Step functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by putting the lock on the function/service which triggers the step function.

For example, if you trigger the step function from a Lambda (External to the step function), you can put the lock in the invoking Lambda function. To implement the lock, you might need an external storage to keep execution state.

Answer (score 5):

Hello I have solved it in the Step-Function by displaying all StepFunction in the Running-State. It will then compare the last entry of the list with the current execution name, if it fits together it runs the normal part, if it deviates it waited 30sec and checked again whether it fits together.

[step-function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/689ni.png)

```
 {
  "StartAt": "ListExecutions",
  "States": {
    "ListExecutions": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Parameters": {
        "StateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:region:account-id:stateMachine:MyStateMachine",
        "StatusFilter": "RUNNING"
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:sfn:listExecutions",
      "Next": "Choice",
      "OutputPath": "$.Executions[-1:]"
    },
    "Choice": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "And": [
            {
              "Variable": "$[0].Name",
              "StringEqualsPath": "$$.Execution.Name"
            }
          ],
          "Next": "dummy processing"
        }
      ],
      "Default": "waiting for completion"
    },
    "dummy processing": {
      "Type": "Wait",
      "Seconds": 15,
      "End": true
    },
    "waiting for completion": {
      "Type": "Wait",
      "Seconds": 30,
      "Next": "ListExecutions"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This works! Thank you, very much.
In my case, I am using ResultPath in the first 'ListExecutions' step, to append the event details that needs to be passed to next step as "ResultPath": "$.taskresult" and had to remove "OutputPath": "$.Executions[-1:]". 
Now in the 'Choice' step, when I need non-zero index 'N' to verify the execution ID "Variable": "$.taskresult.Executions[N].Name" since the newest execution is at the top of the json. How can I accomplish this usecase? Any hints will be really helpful

Comment: Ok. "IsPresent": false in Choice step against "Variable": "$.taskresult.Executions[1].Name". This checks that there's only one execution running at a time, since [1] represents there are 2 or more executions. This works for me. Will look for more sophisticated approach.

Comment: As step functions is an eventually consistent API this solution does not guarantee that only one is running at a time